# Magento 2: Display Swatchs in my template file

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, configurable-swatches, visualswatch

I am fetching configuration products from SKU, I am displaying configuration by dropdown, and using selected value I am generating proper SKU of that product.

Ex: if customer select 'MH01' and select configure color:'Black' & Size:'S', the product's SKU will be 'MH01-S-Black' and it's working perfectly fine but now I want to replace configure dropdown by swatches. 
I am already getting the value of attributes for the swatch, but not successfully display to my template file.

Here is my controller:

```
           $getProduct = $this->getRequest()->getParam('get_product');
           $productDetail = $this->productRepository->get($getProduct);
           $data['name'] = $productDetail->getName();
           $data['id'] = $productDetail->getId();
           $data['sku'] = $productDetail->getSku();
           $data['price'] = $productDetail->getFinalPrice();
           $data['stock'] = $productDetail->getQuantityAndStockStatus();
           $data['config'] = $this->configurable->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($productDetail);


           $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
           $result->setData($data);
           return $result;
```

as per my knowledge, $data['config'] have an all attribute value for swatches, please correct me if I am wrong.

Source: [how to get swatches attribute option in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164791/how-to-get-swatches-attribute-option-in-magento-2)

Data in $data['config']: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vV1EwHqzjO1RZHkpQ6KGR19qb5jxgRVL/view?usp=sharing

My template viewproduct.phtml (writing only AJAX)

```
require(['jquery'],function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var data = '';
        jQuery("#load_product").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var getProduct = jQuery("#get_product").val();
            var url = "<?php echo $block->getUrl('viewproduct/loadproduct/index');?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {get_product:getProduct},
                showLoader: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    data = response;
                    if (!jQuery.trim(response)) {
                        alert("Product is not configurable");
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        jQuery("#newProduct").html('');
                        jQuery("#example").css('visibility', 'visible');
                        jQuery('.productName').html('');
                        jQuery('.productName').html(response.name);
                        jQuery('.productPrice').html('');
                        jQuery('.productPrice').html(response.price+'$');
                        jQuery.each(response.config, function (index,value) {
                            var select = value.label + '<select class="configurable"  name="' + index + '" >';
                            jQuery.each(value.values, function (key, opt) {
                                select += '<option value="' + opt.value_index + '">' + opt.label + '</option>>'
                            });
                            select += '</select>';
                            jQuery("#newProduct").append(select);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I also tried other answers to display swatches, but

1. they are using objectManager.
2. mostly answer showing swatches for category page or productList.

like:[How to get visual swatch image from attribute_id?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177479/how-to-get-visual-swatch-image-from-attribute-id?rq=1)

I need swatches for specific products which users asking, I am getting data from AJAX request.

Any help, a suggestion would be appreciated